# start-dfs.sh: command not found on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop 2.2.0. on Ubuntu 12.04. But the command `start-dfs.sh` is not working. When I run this command it returns `start-dfs.sh: command not found`. `start-dfs.sh`, `start-all.sh`, `stop-dfs.sh` and `stop-all.sh` are in the `sbin` directory. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first solution

Setup Hadoop Environment Variables

```
$cd ~
$vi .bashrc
 
paste following to the end of the file
 
#Hadoop variables
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
###end of paste
 
$ cd /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
$ vi hadoop-env.sh
 
#modify JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/
```

close the file and execute this command

```
source .bashrc
start-all.sh
```

if not work restart and try above command

second solution

go to sbin directory of hadoop

```
cd /home/kishore/hadoop/sbin
  ./start-all.sh
```

Note- make sure about permission and owner should be right.